# How to remove last blank from printed line in python3?

Tags: python, printing, nonblank

I want to remove the last blank from printed line.

example)

```py
list=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(2):
    print(list[i], end=" ")
>>> 1 2
```

There is a one ***blank*** after '2' in printed line. How can I modify the code to remove the last blank?

Comment: Is there a Trim function?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "list unpacking" similar to [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) in conjunction with slices.

For example:

```
print(*list[:2])
```

Returns:

```
1 2
```

+ new line symbol `\n`

To remove the `\n` symbol, you can use this code.

```
print(*list[:2], end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this `" ".join(map(str, [list[i] for i in range(2)]))`.

Answer (score 0):

The blank is due to the argument `end = " "` in print function. This essentially tells the python program to add a `" " (blank)` instead of newline after every print. So you can either remove it or do something like this in your for loop.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(2) :
     if (i != range(2)[-1]) :
          print (list[i], end = " ")
     else :
          print (list[i], end='')
```

This tells the python program to not use the extra space or  newline at the end of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop for this

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=' '.join(map(str,a[:2]))
```

will do

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(2):
    if  i == max(range(2)):
        print(list[i])
    else:
        print(list[i], end=" ")

1 2
```

If you mean you always want to cut the last space but keep the others, how about adding if?